# Is there a way to account for punctuation in this simple for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

Currently, I am creating a code where a random song will be selected and the first letters of each word shall be printed, along with the artist's name, and the user has to try and guess the song name. I want to be able to make this code to account for punctuation like apostrophes.

Ex:-

> Currently output - `"I__ A B_______ - Smash Mouth"`
>
> Expected output -  `"I'_ A B_______ - Smash Mouth"`.

Could anyone let me know of a simple way to do this?

My current code is as follows:

```
print(' '.join(x[0] + '_' * (len(x) - 1) for x in string.split()))
```

Comment: can you post an example of the "string" you are trying to split?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to replace letters only. Use [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace letters with `'_'`:

```py
>>> import re
>>> s = "I'm A Believer"
>>> print(' '.join(x[0] + re.sub("[a-zA-Z]", '_', x[1:]) for x in s.split()))
I'_ A B_______
```

A more interesting example:

```py
>>> s = "Hello, I love you! - Don't you?"
>>> print(' '.join(x[0] + re.sub("[a-zA-Z]", '_', x[1:]) for x in s.split()))
H____, I l___ y__! - D__'_ y__?
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re` you could match all

- letters   `[a-zA-Z]`
- which are not preceded by a space   `(?<! )`

The latter is called a negative lookbehind assertion:

```
import re
s = "I'm A Believer"
s[0] + re.sub(r'(?<! )[a-zA-Z]', '.', s[1:])

# I'. A B.......
```